# I am trying to understand why we used lower semicontinuous functions to induce a fuzzy topology, and need some help understanding this.

Tags: general-topology

Context:
I am trying to understand why when inducing a fuzzy topology, we would want to use functions that are lower semicontinuous. I have not studied nets, just introductory topology. I did some research and found the following quote from an article.

Quote:
“Our definition of "open" fuzzy set in $X$, we employ the heuristic principle that $A$ is "closed" if whenever $\{x_v,v∈D\}$ is a net in $(X,T)$ converging to a point $x∈X$, then $x$ is "at least as much in $A$ as the $x$ ultimately are," i.e., $A(x)≥sup_{v∈D}A(x_v)$."

Source/citation context:
The above quote comes from Micheal D. Weiss paper "Fixed Points, Separation, and Induced Topologies for Fuzzy Sets". He makes the above statement to say that an upper semicontinuous function is closed. He uses it to motivate his definition of an induced fuzzy topology from a crisp topology.

Question:
What does the details of the justification in the quote mean?

Better yet:
How does this show upper semicontinuous functions are closed?

****EDIT
I removed \mathcal{T} and \mathcal{D} since they weren't compiling correctly.

Comment: I gather that if upper semicontinuous functions are closed then our open sets are lower semicontinuous functions. 

But how do we justify upper semicontinuous functions are closed?